# Previously working .apk now crashes upon launch on Oculus Quest 2 without any changes made

Tags: apk, virtual-reality, oculus, unreal-engine5, oculusquest

Problem:
-Meta Quest Developer Hub (.apk built from Unreal Engine 5.0.3) crashes upon launching.
-App launch was working fine 6 hours before my Oculus was left switched on unattended (went to bed, woke up, did nothing to change anything and it didn't work anymore. was able to launch + cast prior). Assumption is that my Oculus had an auto update and is not compatible with initial .apk file anymore (used an old working .apk file to test and it crashes upon launching as well).

Have tried to troubleshoot but to no avail:

- factory reseting oculus + changing a new oculus set
- reinstalling several backed-up .apk files which used to work prior to sleeping
- repackaging .apk from my different backed-up unreal projects

Imported a sample VR template from UE5 and packaged it, .apk app launches successfully on Oculus. However, migrating my project file into the new template causes the new .apk to fail launch.
Rebuilding my entire game from VR template is too time consuming.

Any solutions/troubleshooting suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Please send help!